# On inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: inverse-function

Can we always write tan^-1 (x) as cot^-1(1/x),sin^-1(x) as cosec^-1(x) and sec^-1(x) as cos^-1 (x) or are there any restrictions on this fact because of domain ?

Comment: To be clear... when you use $~^{-1}$ are you talking about functional inverse or multiplicative inverse?  E.g. when you say $\sin^{-1}(x)$ do you mean $\arcsin(x)$ or do you mean $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$?

Comment: Is the logic here
$$
\tan{y} = x \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad \frac{1}{\tan{x}} =\text{cot}{x} = \frac{1}{y}
$$
?

Comment: I mean Arc sin x

Comment: @MattiP. you seem to have mixed up your y's and x's.

Comment: How have I mixed up my y's and X's?...I can't read what you have written mathematically..

Comment: I made that message to MattiP, not to you Schwarz.  Matti had written $\tan (\color{red}{y})=x \iff \frac{1}{\tan(\color{red}{x})}=\frac{1}{y}$.  The variables in red should have matched

Comment: In any case., yes, $\arctan(x)$ is the same as $\text{arccot}(\frac{1}{x})$ almost everywhere, and similarly for the others.  The places where it doesn't match would be due to division by zero errors.

Comment: Yes, I made a typo there. Oopsie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle values for the inverse functions were chosen exactly with the intent that $$\operatorname{Arcsin}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arccsc}(x),\quad \operatorname{Arccsc}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arcsin}(x)$$
$$\operatorname{Arccos}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arcsec}(x),\quad \operatorname{Arcsec}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arccos}(x)$$
everywhere in their domains except for $x = 0$.

However, it is common to take $\left(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right)$ as the range of $\operatorname{Arctan}$, but $(0,\pi)$ as the range of $\operatorname{Arccot}$. Therefore

$$\operatorname{Arctan}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arccot}(x),\quad \operatorname{Arccot}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arctan}(x)$$
holds for $x > 0$, but 
$$\operatorname{Arctan}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arccot}(x) - \pi,\quad \operatorname{Arccot}\left(\frac 1x\right) = \operatorname{Arctan}(x) + \pi$$
holds for $x < 0$.